# Java storing multiple images, config files and such in an indexed file?

Tags: java, caching

I have seen a few programs and games that store their data in an indexed file, and they load their data from that file which they usually call `cache`.

I want to be able to load my data in this way:

```
final int SPRITES_INDEX = 3;

List<Sprite> sprites = (List<Sprite>) cache.loadIndex(SPRITES_INDEX);
```

Does any know how it's done and why its done this way? or is there a name for this method of storing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look up "resources" in "jar" files.  That's what is commonly used for this job in the java world.  Normally a jar file is just a zip file, which is sequential, but many years ago they added the ability to have indexed jar files, which provide random access to their contents.

You can begin here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

(Look for the "i" option which adds an index to the jar file.)

Comment: I'm not sure if he really means indexed files... From the gaming context of his question, he might actually be talking about a `Texture Package` (aka `Texture Atlas`). But until that is specified, you answer is perfectly reasonable, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

At least for images/rendering, this is called `Texture Packing`, and is done because OpenGL "binds" images before rendering them, and this binding can be expensive, processing-wise.

Packaging the textures inside a larger image allows the game/app to bind only once, and then, based on an index of predefined pixel coordinates, render only parts of the larger image, as if they were separate smaller images.

I suggest taking a look at LibGDX's [`TexturePacker`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#texturepacker).

Extract:

> In OpenGL, a texture is bound, some drawing is done, another texture
>   is bound, more drawing is done, etc. Binding the texture is relatively
>   expensive, so it is ideal to store many smaller images on a larger
>   image, bind the larger texture once, then draw portions of it many
>   times. libgdx has a TexturePacker class which is a command line
>   application that packs many smaller images on to larger images. It
>   stores the locations of the smaller images so they are easily
>   referenced by name in your application using the TextureAtlas class.
>
> TexturePacker uses multiple packing algorithms but the most important
>   is based on the maximal rectangles algorithm. It also uses brute
>   force, packing with numerous heuristics at various sizes and then
>   choosing the most efficient result.

---

Note that this is a type of, and similar but not identical to, the general concept of `Caching`.

In computer programming, caching consists of dedicating a section of memory to storing recently or frequently used data, to avoid having to recreate/reprocess that data every time it is needed/accessed.

As such, it's similar, but not the same to the concept of texture-packing, which instead is done not to recreate/reprocess the images themselves, but rather to avoid an expensive complication/process further down the line.

Considering the gaming context of the question, it's also important to note that another concept, this time much closer to caching, exists. It's called `Pooling`, and consists of creating a cache (in this case called `Pool`) of pre-created/pre-processed instances of objects that can be expected to be needed in varied quantity over time, for examples the units in an RTS game, to avoid having to create them when they are needed (in turn to avoid sudden "weight" in processing, which leads to sudden drops in FPS, or "stutters", in the context of a game).

Comment: I did not think of this, because the OP mentions "storing multiple images, config files", which to me, directly points to jar files.  (But he mentions this in the *title*, not in the body of the question.)